# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo because com.myappliaction not taking the value

Tags: android, kotlin

a am new to this, i dont know where i have done the mistake please help me...
androidmanifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dell.myapplication">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>    </application>



</manifest>
```

---

```
mainactivity.kt

    package com.example.dell.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.Manifest.permission
import android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import java.util.jar.Manifest


const val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.dell.myapplication.MESSAGE"


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }

    fun sendMessage(view: View) {


        // Do something in response to button
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val message = editText.text.toString()

        val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
        }
        print(EXTRA_MESSAGE)
        startActivity(intent)
        }
}
```

---

```
displaymessage.kt

    package com.example.dell.myapplication

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import android.content.Intent


class DisplayMessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)




    }
    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    val message = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2).apply {
        text = message
    }
}
```

string.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">myapplication</string>
<string name="edit_message">enter a message</string>
<string name="button_send">send</string>
```

here is the error log

```
04-17 12:27:15.657 12925-12925/com.example.dell.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dell.myapplication, PID: 12925
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dell.myapplication/com.example.dell.myapplication.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2750)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:186)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6006)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:937)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:798)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dell.myapplication.DisplayMessageActivity.<init>(DisplayMessageActivity.kt:20)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2750) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:186) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6006) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:937) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:798) 
04-17 12:27:15.720 12925-12925/com.example.dell.myapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12925 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I can say that your `intent` is null for some reason. Ok, I see the reason - you are calling it outside of `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the NPE on calling `intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)` in `DisplayMessageActivity`. It is because you are trying to initialize that field (`val message`) before the `intent` of that `Activity`actually gets set.

Instead of that, you should move your code to `onCreate` and work with `intent` there. Also, as Nilesh suggests, you need to move findViewById also to `onCreate`, because the content layout has not been set yet.

Your `message` and `textView` fields are initialized when the system instantiate the activity class, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform **`findViewById`** inside `onCreate()` method

Try this

```
class DisplayMessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.dell.myapplication.MESSAGE"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        val message = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2).apply {
        text = message
    }


    }

}
```